# Is there a limit on the amount of current that an Arduino relay can handle?

Tags: arduino

I have made an Arduino Project in which I use an Arduino UNO, ESP8266, a water sensor and a relay. I am trying to control the AC water pump with the help of a relay.
So I have a doubt whether a 5V single channel relay could handle a AC Water Pump of 1HP connected to 240V ?

Comment: There's a limit to how much current an ESP8266 or Arduino UNO port can source. Check the specifications on your relay for what it requires.

Comment: You have to check the datasheet of the relay that you use to learn its current capabilities.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not the microcenter current that you need to check but the relay's specifications.

For practically let's assume your Arduino can drive your relay's coil, in most cases it has enough milliamps to do so, now, will your relay carry the power requirements of the motors, in amps and volts?

Check out the maximum AC rating of the relay's contacts and leave enough margin for safety.

Comment: this site is about coding. please don't answer off-topic questions.